# Calculate a state not by its derivative in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[image: derivative state space representation]

I have a system with state space representation. This system intakes input $u_1$ and $u_2$. There are two nonlinear blocks. One generates state $x_3$ and two internal states $x_1$, $x_2$. And the other one generates output $x_6$ and two internal states $x_4$, $x_5$. Here $x_7$ is the derivative of $x_3$:

$$X=[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7]^T$$
$$U=[u_1,u_2]^T$$

Since there are nonlinear blocks, it seems I cannot convert the model into

$$\dot{X}=f(X,U)$$

Instead, I wil have:

$$\dot{X}=f(X,\dot{X},U)$$

I was thinking about such a representation:

$$\dot{X}_{1-6}=f(\dot{X}_{1-6},U)$$
$$x_7=\dot{x}_3$$

This representation solves the problem of taking derivative from $x_3$ since

$$\dot{x}_7=\ddot{x}_3$$

The disadvantage is that is makes my code segmented. I will use [odeint library](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/examples.html) (C++ solver) for my numerical calculation which expects to give it a derivative vector. Beside that, having states which are calculated directly, generate some problems which are related to ODE internal error calculation and dependency on the order of calculation. By the order of calculation, I mean if you say

```
// Pseudo-code
function RHS(&X,U)
   X(7)=Xdot(3)
   Xdot(1)=...
   ....
   Xdot(6)=...
```

Is different from

```
// Pseudo-code
function RHS(&X,U)
   Xdot(1)=...
   ....
   Xdot(6)=...
   X(7)=Xdot(3)
```

And you can imagine how much it can affect the accuracy or introduce bugs.

Can someone explain me if it is a good idea to calculate a state not by its derivative and does it disrupt ODE accuracy?

Comment: Are the blocks non-linear only in the inputs $u_1$ and $u_2$?  Also, the only derivative I see is with $x_7$.  Why don't the U's appear in the code? Are you trying to take an implicit relationship between the $x_i$'s?

Comment: @Paul thanks for mentioning the dependency on U vector. I fixed that. however I did not catch the other questions. The blocks are nonlinear in front of inputs. I may add some nonlinear blocks other part of the model later. I prefer to consider it general. For implicit relationship, only for $x_7$ (as a function of $\dot{x}_3$) not for all states.

Comment: I just mention that because it appears the system is nonlinear in the inputs only, so that $x_i=f(u_1,u_2)$ for $i \in \lbrace 1,...,6 \rbrace$ and $x_7=\dot{x_3}$.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Paul I am afraid not. in [state space representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) $\dot{X}=f(X,U)$ not $X=f(X,U)$. Since the system is nonlinear, what is written in Wikipedia does not change to function form (rather than the linear form)

Comment: @Paul this [link](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/101108047/module4/Lecture%209.pdf) might show nonlinear ODE better (page 12).

Comment: I understand the standard state space representation.  I am just noting what the actual blocks you draw out are not the same as the differential equations you describe.

Comment: @Paul the blocks have dynamics with nonlinear properties(such as transfer function with saturation). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Seems stackexchange is crazy. I could not add any tag nor revert my own edit. If you have over 2K, please add ODE tag to the collection of tags.